# Why can't I get my JWT from cookies when hitting the /authenticate endpoint in my React app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt

This is driving me insane. I'm writing an app with React + Express. This is how my `app.js` looks:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const userRoutes = require('./src/Database/Routes/userRoutes');

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(cookieParser())

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3030

app.use(cors({
  origin: "http://localhost:3000"
  credentials: true, // <= Accept credentials (cookies) sent by the client
})

app.use(express.static('frontend/build'));

app.use('/api/users', cookieParser(), userRoutes);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

And this is my `userRoutes.js`:

```
//importing modules
const express = require('express')
const userController = require('../Controllers/userController')
const { signup, login, authenticate } = userController
const userAuth = require('../Middleware/userAuth');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/signup', userAuth.saveUser, signup);

router.post('/login', login);

router.post('/authenticate', userAuth.validateUser, authenticate);

module.exports = router
```

my `/login` end point works greate, creating a JWT. This is the login function:

```
const login = async (req, res) => {

  try {

    const { email, password } = req.body;

    const user = await User.findOne({
      where: {
        email: email
      }

    });

    if (!user) return res.status(401).send("No user found")

    const isSame = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (!isSame) return res.status(401).send("Password failed");

    let token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
      expiresIn: MILISECONDS
    });
    
// Set the token
    res.cookie("jwt", token, { maxAge: MILISECONDS , httpOnly: true });
    return res.status(201).send({
      message: "Login Successful",
      email,
      token,
      ok: true
    });
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

But when I'm trying to hit the `/authenticate` endpoint nothing is there...

```
const authenticate = async (req, res) => {
  console.log("req.headers is", req.headers);
//
req.header is
{
host: 'localhost:3030',
connection: 'keep-alive',
'content-length': '0',
'sec-ch-ua': '"Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"',
'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
'content-type': 'application/json',
accept: '*/*',
origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
referer: 'http://localhost:3000/',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,es-419;q=0.8,es;q=0.7,ru;q=0.6'
 }
//
console.log("req.cookie", req.cookie);
 //
req.cookie is
[Object: null prototype] {}
//
  return res.status(200);
}
```

...except if I use postman, in which case it works fine. BUT If I do it from my react app it's uselsess. Here's my react code:

```
  // LOGIN
    const POST_USER = async (data) => {

        let response = await fetch('http://localhost:3030/api/users/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            // "credentials": "include" <- This breaks the request even with cors configured
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        });

        response = response.json();

        return response;

    };

 // AUTHENTICATE
    const IS_AUTH = async () => {

        let auth = await fetch('http://localhost:3030/api/users/authenticate', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        });
        
        auth = await auth.json();
        
        return auth;

    }
```

What am I missing?

To be able to get the JWT from the cookies.

Comment: First issue I see is you've registered the `cookieParser` middleware twice; the first time globally with `app.use()` and the second time as inline middleware for the `/api/users` route. This may not be a problem but it's certainly unnecessary

Comment: _`"credentials": "include" <- This breaks the request`_... how does it break? What is going wrong with this part.

Comment: I just realized I missed the credentials in the service that's hitting the `/authenticate` endpoint... that seems to fix it, thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

it's very likely the react app is not on the same origin as the express api localhost:3030, if the 'page' and the api are on different ports the cookie is not same origin and that credentials option has no effect at all, the cookie is not for your origin and that's why you dont see it, period. Try assigning the JWT to the Authorization header (a `Bearer`) instead of cookie.

Look for "typically in the Authorization header using the Bearer schema" in https://jwt.io/introduction for directions